# Firebase Analytics initialise for unit test (Mockito) in Android

Tags: android, mockito, firebase-analytics

I am running a unit test with

> @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

I have used firebase Analytics to log events

> MyApplication.getAnalytics().getInstance(appContext).logEvent(eventType, bundle)

and this in my Application class

```
public static FirebaseAnalytics getAnalytics() {
        return FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(appContext);
    }
```

Now while running tests, I am getting `NullPointerException`. What will be the right way to initialize Analytics for my unit tests or just ignore them.

I am not getting the context in case I try to initialize it in my setup method of tests.

Comment: try passing appContext as a parameter in method and then use it

Comment: adding stacktrace can help people debug better, can you add that too

Comment: How did you get `appContext`? Could you please share the entire unit test?

Comment: Can you please post stacktrace with exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock application class that extends your application class and then overrides getAnalytics with a stubbed value or mock object.  Also you should make your getAnalytics method non-static as it's easier for testing and you can pass the reference via dependency injection or you can use a static reference to the application class (but that isn't very testable so I would choose the first option)

```
public class MockApplication extends MyApplication {
    public FirebaseAnalytics getAnalytics() {
        return mock(FirebaseAnalytics.class)
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `@Config` annotation to configure your test runner like this

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.M, application = MockApplication.class)
```

Comment: I am not using Roboelectric to run my tests, is there any way to do it using Mockito only?

Comment: It is possible but you will have to do a lot of mocking and handle returns from most of the context methods like `getResources()` so it'll take you a long time.  I would suggest using robolectric for any tests that touch android code.  Making your app more modular with an architecture like Uber Ribs will help you have classes that you can test with pure Junit.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/Using-PowerMock

Refactor yours like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(FirebaseAnalytics.class)
public class TestClass {

   @Rule
   public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
   private FirebaseAnalytics firebase;

   @Test
   public void testMocking() {
      firebase = PowerMockito.mock(FirebaseAnalytics.class);
      Context context = PowerMockito.mock(Context.class);

      PowerMockito.mockStatic(FirebaseAnalytics.class);
      Mockito.when(FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)).thenReturn(firebase);
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Roboelectric to run my tests, is there any way to do it using Mockito only?